# C#/CS1061 - Error with referencing property of a class returned from stack

Tags: c#, visual-studio, class

I currently have this code, It constructs and pushes a class into a stack, then "pops" the object out of a stack, and logs a property from it.

```
public class Class {

    public static Stack<object> ExampleStack = new Stack<object>();

    public class ExampleClass 
    { 
        public string A {get; set;}
        public int b {get; set;}
        public int C {get; set;}
        
        ExampleClass(string a, int b, int c) 
        {
            A=a;
            B=b;
            C=c;
        }
    }
    void main() 
    {
         ExampleStack.Push(new ExampleClass("E", 1, 2));
    }
    
    public static void TestStack() 
    {
        Temp = ExampleStack.Pop();
        Console.Log(Temp.A);
    }
}
```

I cannot figure out why `Temp.A` Gives the error CS1061 before compiling in visual studio.

Any help is appreciated

Comment: Whats the error stack?

Answer (score 3):

You need to change this line:

```
public static Stack<object> ExampleStack = new Stack<object>();
```

to this:

```
public static Stack<ExampleClass> ExampleStack = new Stack<ExampleClass>();
```

CS1061 says: *'type' does not contain a definition for 'member' and no extension method 'name' accepting a first argument of type 'type' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?).*

You were trying to call `Temp.A`, but `Temp` is of type `object` and doesn't implement `A`

You will probably also have to move the `ExampleClass` object in to it's own CS file.

ExampleClass.cs:

```
public class ExampleClass 
{ 
    public string A {get; set;}
    public int B {get; set;}
    public int C {get; set;}
    
    public ExampleClass(string a, int b, int c) 
    {
        A=a;
        B=b;
        C=c;
    }
}
```

Program.cs:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public static class Program
{
    private static readonly Stack<ExampleClass> ExampleStack = new Stack<ExampleClass>();
    
    static int Main()
    {
        ExampleStack.Push(new ExampleClass("E", 1, 2));
        TestStack();
        return 0;
    } 
    
    public static void TestStack() 
    {
        var Temp = ExampleStack.Pop();
        Console.WriteLine(Temp.A);
    }
}
```

Comment: Also: `Temp` is not declared and the second property is named `b` but the example tries to set `B`. `Console.Log` doesn't exist, `TestStack` is never called.

Comment: @Andy, Thanks, that completely fixed my problem.

Comment: @TheJack If this answer helps, please click `√` to mark it as answer.